# How do I get rid of this RunTimeError when trying some code out of Chapter 12 of the Beginning Ruby book?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error, bots

Sorry if this is a total newbie question, but I am not sure how to solve this problem.  I'm currently getting these errors when I try to run the code below:

```
bot.rb:58:in `rescue in initialize': Can't load bot data (RunTimeError)

bot.rb:55:in `initialize'

basic_client.rb:3:in `new'

basic_client.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

Here is the source code for bot.rb, and the error appears to be at the
"@data = YAML.load(File.open(options[:data_file]).read)" part.

```
# A basic implementation of a chatterbot
class Bot
  attr_reader :name

  # Initializes the bot object, loads in the external YAML data
  # file and sets the bot's name. Raises an exception if
  # the data loading process fails.
  def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
    begin
      @data = YAML.load(File.open(options[:data_file]).read)
    rescue
      raise "Can't load bot data"
    end
  end
```

This is the source code for basic_client.rb file:

```
require './bot'

bot = Bot.new(:name => ARGV[0], :data_file => ARGV[1])

puts bot.greeting

while input = $stdin.gets and input.chomp != 'end'
  puts '>> ' + bot.response_to(input)
end

puts bot.farewell
```

If anyone could help me that'd be great.  Also if you need more information or clarification in regards to the problem, I can provide that too.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you `require 'yaml'`?  In addition to @mu's suggestion, you might change `raise "Can't load bot data"` to `raise "Can't load bot data from '#{options[:data_file]}'"`.

Comment: Ya I did put require 'yaml', but I'm thinking maybe I didn't reference another file properly or there's something related to other files that are associated with the one I'm trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rescue so that you can see the full message:

```
 rescue => e
  raise "Can't load bot data because: #{e}"
```

Then I would say that getting an error there means that either your file is malformed (check its syntax with http://yamllint.com/) or the path is not correct. You need to make sure you are correctly passing the path of your yaml file to basic_client.rb as the second argument (ARGV[1]):

```
ruby basic_client.rb "C3PO" "bot.yml"
```

I'm not sure how "bot.yml" should look like, but it must be the data that you expect to be in your `@data` variable.