# Ruby: Chatterbot can't load bot data

Tags: ruby, yaml

I'm picking up ruby language and get stuck at playing  with the chatterbot i have developed. Similar issue has been asked here [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470239/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-runtimeerror-when-trying-some-code-out-of-chapter-12-of) , I did what they suggested to change the rescue in order to see the full message.But it doesn't seem right, I was running  `basic_client.rb`  at `rubybot` directory and `fred.bot` is also generated at that directory . Please see the error message below: Your help very be very much appreciated.

```
Snailwalkers-MacBook-Pro:~ snailwalker$ cd rubybot
Snailwalkers-MacBook-Pro:rubybot snailwalker$ ruby  basic_client.rb
/Users/snailwalker/rubybot/bot.rb:12:in `rescue in initialize': Can't load bot data because: No such file or directory - bot_data (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/snailwalker/rubybot/bot.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from basic_client.rb:3:in `new'
    from basic_client.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

basic_client.rb

```
require_relative 'bot.rb'

bot = Bot.new(:name => 'Fred', :data_file => 'fred.bot')

puts bot.greeting

while input = gets and input.chomp != 'end'
    puts '>> ' + bot.response_to(input)
end

puts bot.farewell
```

bot.rb:

```
require 'yaml'
require './wordplay'

class Bot
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(options)
    @name = options[:name] || "Unnamed Bot"
    begin
      @data = YAML.load(File.read('bot_data'))
    rescue => e
      raise "Can't load bot data because: #{e}"
    end
  end

  def greeting
    random_response :greeting
  end

  def farewell
    random_response :farewell
  end

  def response_to(input)
    prepared_input = preprocess(input).downcase
    sentence = best_sentence(prepared_input)
    reversed_sentence = WordPlay.switch_pronouns(sentence)
    responses = possible_responses(sentence)
    responses[rand(responses.length)]
  end

  private

  def possible_responses(sentence)
    responses = []

    @data[:responses].keys.each do |pattern|
      next unless pattern.is_a?(String)

      if sentence.match('\b' + pattern.gsub(/\*/, '') + '\b')
        if pattern.include?('*')
          responses << @data[:responses][pattern].collect do |phrase|
            matching_section = sentence.sub(/^.*#{pattern}\s+/, '')
            phrase.sub('*', WordPlay.switch_pronouns(matching_section))
          end
        else
          responses << @data[:responses][pattern]
        end
      end
    end

    responses << @data[:responses][:default] if responses.empty?
    responses.flatten

  end

  def preprocess(input)
    perform_substitutions input
  end

  def perform_substitutions(input)
    @data[:presubs].each {|s| input.gsub!(s[0], s[1])}
    input
  end

  # select best_sentence by looking at longest sentence
  def best_sentence(input)
    hot_words = @data[:responses].keys.select do |k|
      k.class == String && k =~ /^\w+$/
    end

    WordPlay.best_sentence(input.sentences, hot_words)
  end

  def random_response(key)
    random_index = rand(@data[:responses][key].length)
    @data[:responses][key][random_index].gsub(/\[name\]/, @name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `bot.rb` also at `rubybot` directory ?

Comment: Yes, it is at rubybot directory

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad question actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to load the `:data_file` passed into `Bot.new`, but right now you are statically loading a `bot_data` file everytime. You never mentioned about `bot_data` in the question. So if I'm right it should be like this :

```
 @data = YAML.load(File.read(options[:data_file]))
```

Instead of :

```
 @data = YAML.load(File.read('bot_data'))
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, How come i didn't see that one. I have been looking back and force many times !

Comment: It happens. Glad you figured it out now.